# I'm trying to run my new react project on my server

Tags: node.js, reactjs

Every time run my project:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'; 

import App from './App.js '


ReactDom.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

it keeps bringing back this error
[Failed to compile.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NKWC.png)

I've also reinstalled `react-dom`

but it Doesn't work.

Comment: Well is `App.js` really located next to `index.js` ? Seems like it can't find that path.

Comment: First be sure that the App.js directory is correct, if it is you should provide more information about the App.js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try two things : 
First, replace `./App.js`  by only `App`
Second, I don't know if a space can fail your import but it looks like you have one on your import.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure './App.js' is the right path of the App component?
Because it is not being found on this path.